# Android Studio writing app to Nexus 5 wont work

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting this error when i try to build to my phone

"Failed to find byte code for android/telephony/TelephonyManager$CellInfoCallback"

It builds and syncs fine but won't build to the device, I've also gotten it working with the virtual machine.

I'm currently using this github, https://github.com/usnistgov/LTECoverageTool/tree/master

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Reqpl.png)